# How do I insert a SuperColumn with python/thrift?

Tags: python, cassandra, thrift

Using the python/thrift interface I am trying to insert a SuperColumn just like the Comments example in [WTF is a Supercolumn..](http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model)

I've gotten as far as to create the SuperColumn and figured out that I should use batch_mutate to insert it. But I don't know how to create the Mutation and set the key and SuperColumn type

```
keyspace = "Keyspace1"

col1 = Column(name = "commenter", value = "J Doe", timestamp = time.time())
col2 = Column(name = "email", value = "jdoe@example.com", timestamp = time.time())

sc = SuperColumn(name = str(uuid.uuidl()), [col1, col2])

# i am guessing the missing code goes here

mutation = Mutation(column_or_supercolumn = sc?)
client.batch_mutate(keyspace, mutation, ConsistencyLevel.ZERO)
```

Comment: why not use a high level client api? (http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use pycassa or something to make life easier, but something like:

```
keyspace = "Keyspace1"
tableName = "Super1"
key = "jdoe"
col1 = Column(name = "commenter", value = "J Doe", timestamp = time.time())
col2 = Column(name = "email", value = "jdoe@example.com", timestamp = time.time())

newData = [Mutation(ColumnOrSuperColumn(None,
                             SuperColumn(str(uuid.uuidl()),
                                        [col1, col2])))]
dataMap = {key : {tableName : newData}}

client.batch_mutate(keyspace=keyspace,
                    mutation_map=dataMap,
                    consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ZERO)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did use pycassa in the end as it makes life easier-